# Qualtrics- issue on API

Tags: django, qualtrics

The Qualtrics access token can be accessed from the account settings, but I can't, because it asks to upgrade my account and I don't want to do that because it is for a test purpose.I referred some websites and come up with a API url to get the access token.But it requires client ID and client secret. I couldn't find them in my account.If any one can help me where can I find them or giving another way to get the access token and API call url , it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't licensed to use the API, you can't get an API token and can't use the API. The API to get an API Token is meant for Brand Administrator's to get the tokens of others in their organization.